# What is the status of Lorentz Invariance in String Theory ? Is it global or local?

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory, lorentz-symmetry

The questions is simple, what is the status of lorentz invariance in string theory ? Is it global or is it only local ? The proof of absence of anomalies assumes lorentz invariance. However, I believe one can consider some spacetimes where one or more dimensions are compactified. I guess then you can't have lorentz invariance ?

Edit: I have seen statements like Lorentz Symmetry is exactly preserved in String Theory. What does that mean ?

Comment: You always have Lorentz Invariance.

Comment: @Jake That is what I am asking. In what sense exactly ?